# CSS button with description

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, button

I am trying to achieve the following using bootstrap button and custom css. I am not sure how to add a separation with a button and have two sets of labels within it. So far, I am able to create a button with label in it.

[Working codeply demo](http://www.codeply.com/go/PhuqcSftsN])

[image]

Comment: @CristianMatthiasAmbæk Yes thats what I am trying to achieve but clickable

Comment: Putting a <a> tag around the divs containing the product and lable info will make it clickable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,
**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/UI_Designer/ko9yrtzc/1/)**

```
.productButton.selected {
    background-color: rgb(0, 146, 143);
    color: #FFF;
}
.productBtnText{
    font-size:25px;
    border-radius:0;
    width:100%;
    border-bottom:2px solid #000;
 }

.productButton{
    border:2px solid #000;    
    margin:0px;
    padding:0;
    height: 100px;
    width: 200px;
    font-size: 15px;
    white-space: normal;
    position: relative;    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tmw0jfde/)**

You can do this with mark-up (html) only:

```
<button>
    <h4>Titel</h4>
    <hr/>
    <span>More</span>
</button>
```

But this will look a bit weird so by adding some css make it look better.

```
button span {
    font-size: 0.7em;
}
button hr {
    margin: 2px;
}
```